# Linux desktop with stacking tabs

Tags: linux, linux-distribution, desktop-environment

I have recently switched from windows to Xubuntu. I picked xubuntu because xfce is light and battle tested.

But my main problem is that xfce window tabs behave like Windows XP, where multiple instance of the same application create multiple instances of tabs on the taskbar panel.

I am wondering if there is a linux desktop that behaves like Windows, where multiple instances of the same application stack into a single tab, which then subsequently pops up to show mini displays of all the windows.